# How do you unlock new costumes?

Tags: pc, the-amazing-spiderman

The PC release of The Amazing Spider-Man seems to have changed the way you unlock special costumes. The tooltip says you unlock them by completing story and side missions, but which story and side missions unlock which costumes?

Answer (score 1):

I know how to unlock some suits:

- Black Suit: progress through the half of the game.
- Future foundation: complete all crimes and green side missions.
- Negative Zone: complete all xtreme challenges.
- Scarlet Spider:collect all 700 comics.

Answer (score 1):

I unlocked the cross species suit after completing the game.

I unlocked the Big Time suit after completing the chapter 02 "Escape Impossible".

I unlocked the classic black suit after making some progress in the game.

I also unlocked the Future Foundation suit by completing the green icon missions in which you have to collect secret information and take some photographs for the article in Oscorp's secret lab. Those icons are green-coloured and you will find them on your cell phone but be careful over there because security in these labs are not a laughing thing.

There are also some sewers type of green icon which is poisoning the drinking water of the people. you have to fight with some of the infected enemies, Rhino and the Chameleon.

Answer (score 1):

I unlocked:

- new black suit - complete game 100%.
- Big Time - complete every side boss fight.
- Future Foundation - do every Oscorp secret lap.
- Classic Black suit - 50% game completion.
- Negetive Zone - done all the Xtreme Challenges.
- Scarlet Spider(2012) - collect 700 piece of the comic book.
- Classic Suit - download any DLC.

Comment: By classic suit, he means the Sam Raimi interpretation of Spider-Man.